# creating a non-uniform, integer distribution using tr1 <random>

Tags: c++, random, distribution

Right now I use the following code to create a uniform distribution of integers with a range. (I took out the seeding code)

```
int random(int min, int max)
{
    static std::mt19937 gen;
    std::uniform_int<int> dist(min, max);
    return dist(gen);

}
```

I am trying to modify it to give a distribution that favors twords the min value, and almost never produces nears the max value. I can see all of the pre-made distributions, but none of them are integer. And also I can't tell which one fits my needs based on any of the documentation. The closest I have come is the chi squared distribution as shown on wikipedia, where k=2

[image]

But I can't figure out, based on the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926121.aspx) how to use it with integers, let alone set the k value.

How can I set up my function to use an appropriate non-uniform, integer distribution?

---

still working on choosing the correct distro: here are the results of `std::poisson_distribution<int> dist((max - min) * .1);` from 0 to 20:
  [image]

not quite there yet, as 0 should be more frequent than 1, but it should help the next person out, will post more results as they come.

---

well my final solution became a combination of methods:

```
int randomDist(int min, int max)
{
    static std::mt19937 gen;
    std::chi_squared_distribution<double> dist(2);

    int x;
    do
    {
    x = (int)(max*dist(gen)/10) + min;
    }
    while (x > max);
    return x;
}
```

giving the result of:

[image]

Comment: In a Poisson distribution 0 will be more frequent than 1 if you choose a parameter less than 1 (it's currently (20−0)*.1 = 2). You'll also get that with a geometric distribution with any parameter. The one you should pick depends on what you're modelling: geometric models the time until an event occurs (e.g., the number of shots needed to score a goal), Poisson models the number event occurrences in an interval of time (e.g., number of goals in a game).

Comment: Well I am using it for a real time genetic algorithm. Instead of having distinct generation, When the time comes to breed one new organism, I sort them by fitness an choose the parents based one this curve.

Comment: @Zak – If you select using the geometric distribution, you could then describe the selection of each parent as a tournament of #1 vs (winner of #2 vs (winner of #3 vs ...)), where #i wins against any #j, i < j, with probability p — sounds quite plausible.

Comment: @Zak: your graph still seems to me a negative exponential distribution; I'd go directly with it.

Comment: @Matteo & @Zak – Yep, `chi_square_distribution(2)` is a special case that is identical to `exponential_distribution(.5)`. Furthermore, `max*exponential_distribution(.5)/10` is the same as `exponential_distrubtion(max*.5/10)`, and `floor(exponential_distribution(max*.5/10))` is the same as `geometric_distribution(1-exp(-max*.5/10))`.

Comment: I was just going to mention that I had realized that exponential at .5 was equivalent to chi square at 2. I have also verified that empirically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are other integer distributions there, they just don't have `int` in their names. They do have `typedef IntType result_type` in their class definitions.

The ones which behave as you describe are:

- [`binomial_distribution`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)`(t, p)`

  This generates numbers in the range 0 ≤ *x* ≤ *t*, so you need to translate the range by `min`. The mean is at *t·p*, so choose a *p* near 0.

  `std::binomial_distribution<int> dist(max - min, .1);`
  `return dist(gen) + min;`
- [`poisson_distribution`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution)`(λ)`

  This generates numbers 0 ≤ x < ∞, but large numbers are progressively less likely. You can censor anything above `max` to limit it to a range. The parameter *λ* is the mean. Choosing it to match the previous example:

  `std::poisson_distribution<int> dist((max - min) * .1);`
  `int x;`
  `do`
      `x = dist(gen) + min;`
  `while (x > max);`
  `return x;`
- [`geometric_distribution`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)`(p)`

  Also generates numbers 0 ≤ x < ∞, but 0 is the most likely outcome and every subsequent number is less likely than the previous. Again choosing the parameter to match the mean of the previous example:

  `std::geometric_distribution<int> dist(1 / ((max - min) * .1 + 1));`
  `int x;`
  `do`
      `x = dist(gen) + min;`
  `while (x > max);`
  `return x;`

You can also use any of the continuous distributions to generate a `double` and then round it to an `int`.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the distributions said in *@aaz*'s great answer, keep in mind that you can also transform your uniform distribution to any probability distribution function you may think of, using [inverse transform sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) (that however is actually feasible only for some "nice" functions) or [rejection sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) (can be applied in any case, but can be computationally expensive).

It seems to me that a distribution that would fit your needs would be the (negative) [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution):

[image: Exponential distribution]

Luckily, it is one of the distributions to which you can apply inverse transform sampling, which means that, having a sample from a uniform [0, 1] distribution, you can get an exponential distribution by applying the formula:

```
x = - ln(1-p)/lambda
```

with `p` is a random value from the uniform distribution and `lambda` is the parameter of the exponential distribution; see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Generating_exponential_variates) for more info.

Once you get `x` (which will be a `double`), just cast it to `int` (or round it with a function like:

```
int round(double val)
{
    // warning: can give counterintuitive results with negative numbers
    return int(val+0.5);
}
```

) to obtain your result.

---

***Edit***

By the way, I didn't notice that even the exponential distribution is already included in `<random>` ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982914.aspx))... well, even better, you don't need to write the code, but a little bit of theory is never wasted `:)`.